# Поля в Qiwi форме

Tags: qiwi, форма

Здравствуйте! Помогите, пожалуйста, я сейчас подключаю `Qiwi` платежную систему (автооплата товара) к магазину, и у меня возникла проблема, мне не хватает полей в форме(они должны и в файл обработчика отправляться). У меня к примеру есть товары магазина и есть баннеры. Мне надо сделать разделение между ними, в других системах типа `WebMoney` или `Perfect Money`. Там можно было добавить 1 поле в котором я указывал тип платежа (товар или баннер), а в `Qiwi` можно добавить такое поле?

Comment: подключи robokassa.ru и будет тебе счастье, пользуюсь радует!

Answer (score 1):

**РЕШЕНО**

Всё что нужно это передавать в параметрах текст примерно такого содержания:
Логин-ID-Комментарий
А потом через

```
$array = explode('-', $comment);
```

Разбирать каждую элемент, как объект массива($array[0] - это будет логин);